# Make Dark Mode Universal

Tags: gnome

Dark mode works for the System UI but for some reason web pages do not detect my dark mode and instead show me light mode pages.

 How can I allow them to see my appearance choice.

Comment: It's helpful if you provide OS & release details (these allow us to know details of what version of GNOME you're working with & details as to your software stack).  GNOME stores settings for GTK apps; but you've not said what apps you're viewing the web pages in (they maybe GTK3/4, Qt3 or other apps, but we can't know until you've provided that detail).  What OS, release & web browser (*or other program*) are you using where *light* appears?

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome you can go to chrome://flags and make "dark mode for web contents" (forgot the exact name) enabled. Relaunch chrome, and all websites will be in dark mode.